# Error 18456 loggin on a SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I had an unexpected system crash and had to setup SQL Server 2016 again. I can connect to the server from SSMS if I use a Windows authentication account, but not via any login created. I keep getting an error 18456:

> Login failed for user 'sa'

Steps:

1. I have enabled SA login and gave it a password but cannot connect via SSMS
2. I have created another login and matched it to my project database, the project database now has the login under its users but again, I cannot log in.
3. SSMS is installed on the actual db server so I doubt this is a remote login issue, but as the db server is isolated from the actual site I would like to update this if needed.

Any ideas would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this is a coding issue...

Comment: @Pikoh: Great! Vote to close then and state that it belongs somewhere else in the SE ecosystem (assuming you haven't already). I'm doing the same with my proposed destination being Database Administrators.

Comment: @BenThul i already did that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you enable the mixed mode authentication?

Did you restart SQL services after changing the mixed mode authentication?

Some of the server level properties takes only after a SQL restart , one such is authentication modes.

Comment: As simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually a SQL Service problem.

Start - > View Local Services -> SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) > restart it